# AngularJS Time & Date not showing in Production

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection

I have the following chunk of Angular code:

```
app.controller('timeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.date = ' EEE, d LLLL yyyy';
  $scope.time = ' h:mm:ss a'
}]);

app.directive("myCurrentTime", function(dateFilter){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        var format;

        scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
            format = value;
            updateTime();
        });

        function updateTime(){
            var dt = dateFilter(new Date(), format);
            element.text(dt);
        }

        function updateLater() {
            setTimeout(function() {
              updateTime(); // update DOM
              updateLater(); // schedule another update
            }, 1000);
        }

        updateLater();
    }
});
```

When I am running my app in my local dev environment, the time and date shows just fine. But when I deploy to production, the time and date does not show, and I am getting an "Error: [$injector:unpr]" log.

Any idea are appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle? Angular is always hard to debug without HTML, especially when dealing with directives. The error also leads me to believe it may be an issue with the directive use.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf8bd86a/

Comment: Are you using something which produces a minified version of your scripts before you deploy them to production?

Comment: Yes... also, if it makes a difference, the Angular is within a RoR app.

Comment: Can you try to run the minified version locally and see if you have the issue?

Comment: Antipod - That does seem to recreate the issue.

Comment: I believe you understand it is hard to say what is going on during the minification process on your side. Anyway, now you know where to dig. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding minification-safe injection.